# how this Grant Access Using Hierarchies works?

Tags: owd, public-group

How this Grant Access Using Hierarchies works. Please explain I am getting confused. Please explain me how this Grant Access Using Hierarchies works in OWD setting, groups etc. Does its use changes at different places. Please explain when record is access to Hierarchies users and when it restricted, when object is made private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Grant Access using Hierarchy is checked for custom object(For standard objects this is always checked) even if the record is private ,users higher in the role than the owner of the record still gets access to the records .

A simple example can be assume opportunity is private OWD and you are Sales Rep owning an opportunity record ,you have your manager who is higher in the role hierarchy than you ,even though opportunity is private he will still get access to your records .

Technically a for every user who has access there will be a share record in the Share table of the Object.

Comment: I am getting confused with this statement when compare with yours. " if the Grant Access Using Hierarchies option is disabled for a custom object, only the record owner and users granted access by the organization-wide defaults receive access to the object's records." this in from role doc by salesforce : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_roles.htm&language=en_US can you please check this.

Comment: Ok so that statement means if grant access using hierarchy is not checked users will have access only if there is a sharing rule providing access to other users .Hope thats clear